# Possible to fire custom binding update except initially?

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding

Let's say I have this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.test= {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        alert("Test");
    }
};
```

The alert fires every time an observable is changed, but also initally when the binding is first evaluated. How can I make the alert fire on every change except initially?

Comment: I'm not sure you can - I think by design it happens initially in order for knockout to work out what observables your binding handler depends on, so it knows when to call it in future.  Internally knockout uses quite clever tracking to know what observables depend on each other, so it isn't constantly running lots of code that it doesn't need to.  I could be wrong though, and there might be a way to stop it from running the update initially, hence this being a comment and not an answer...

Comment: Just re-reading [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), amongst other things it says this about `update`: _"This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element"_, so any method to circumvent this is fighting against the intended use of knockout, rather than working with it.

Comment: This is potentially an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - can you explain _why_ you want to avoid running `update` initially?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way: keep an array of elements that the `update` populates with its element if it's not there (which is the first time it runs) and otherwise does whatever action. Since you've got a custom binding handler, you can just hang the array off of that.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.test = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var seenElements = ko.bindingHandlers.test.seen,
      val = valueAccessor()();
    if (seenElements.indexOf(element) >= 0) {
      alert("Test");
    } else {
      seenElements.push(element);
    }
  }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.test.seen = [];

var vm = {
  alertOn: ko.observable(0),
  raiseAlert: function() {
    vm.alertOn.notifySubscribers();
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="test:alertOn"></div>
<button data-bind="click:raiseAlert">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make the alert fire on every change except initially?

[Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) will call the update callback initially when the binding is applied to an element and track any dependencies (observables/computeds) that you access. When any of these dependencies change, the update callback will be called once again.

I don't think it is possible to fire only by changes and not in initially.

You can create a workaround to fit with your scenario by adding change event tied up with your element inside init.

```
init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
   // element should be the element you want to attach change event.
   $(element).on('change', function (value)
   {
      // do your stuff.
    });
}
```

Comment: That handles when the _element value_ changes, not when the observable/potentially complex chain of observables assigned to the binding handler changes.  Chances are you'd probably want to do what you're suggesting anyway, so you can push any changes in the element back into the observable.